# Qt bar chart with many series in one plot

Tags: c++, qt, bar-chart, qchart

I'm creating a QChart bar plot. 
I have a previously unknown number of QBarSets (I know the number of QBarSets during runtime - but maybe between 1-10) and a, possibly high number of categories (10-1000).

```
QVector<QBarSet*> barSets; 
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){ // n between 1-10
    QBarSet *set = new QBarSet("");
    for(int j=0; j<m; ++j){ // m between 1-1000
        *set << someValue;
    }
    barSets.push_back(set);
}
QBarSeries* series = new QBarSeries();
for(int i=0; i<barSets.count(); ++i){
    series->append(barSets.at(i));
}
```

everything else is almost the same as described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtcharts-barchart-example.html).

My problem is that every bar gets very very tiny. I would like to plot each bar with a fixed width and maybe use a Horizontal Scroll Bar to scroll through the categories.

Does someone have a tiny example how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the answer is very simple. 
you can grep the QBarCategoryAxis very simply using

```
auto axis = qobject_cast<QBarCategoryAxis*>(chart->axisX());
```

and then simply control the visible categories by name

```
auto categories = axis->categories();
QString min = categories.at(n);
QString max = categories.at(m);
axis->setMin(min);
axis->setMax(max);
```

I have used the `horizontalScrollBar_valueChanged` signal to change the min and max category numbers(`n`,`m`).